# Merge PDF if name contains X Python

Tags: python, pdf, merge, contains

I have two folders, folder 1 contains:

```
000000.pdf

123456.pdf

987654.pdf
```

Folder 2 contains:

```
000000 - Name1.pdf

123456 - Name2.pdf

111111 - Name8.pdf
```

I want to write a Python script to merge the pdfs if the number in the names of the files is the same, and skip the file if there is no match. And after merging it, it should be saved using the names in Folder 2. What would be the simples way to do this? The number of files might change and not be equal every time, so I was thinking something like

```
If contains number x:
     merge
Else:
     skip
```

But I have not got it working yet.

Comment: What system are you using?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To merge files use [PyPDF2](https://pypi.org/project/PyPDF2/). To get folder content you have different options but suggest to use [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html). So the solution would look like this:

```
from glob import glob
from pathlib import Path

f1_files = glob(".../*")
f2_files = glob(".../*")

for f1 in f1_files:
    number = Path(f1).stem # Path module is amazing!
    for f2 in f2_files: 
        if number in f2: # we found number in folder_2!
            merger = PdfFileMerger()
            merger.append(f1)
            merger.append(f2)
            merger.write(f2) # f2 here is the name of result file
            break
```

Comment: Thanks! I understand your logic, but the split function only gets rid of the ‘.pdf’ at the end, so it gives a different working directory for each of the folders. Hence, it does not find any files.

I tried to use f1.split(”/“)[-1], but this only works for the first file. Do you know any other way to just get the filenumber from the working directory?

Comment: My wrong, I updated the answer